# Does JustMyCode feature exist for VSCode+CMake Extension?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I have been using VSCode+CMake to build and debug C++ programs. It works fine incorporating third packages from vcpkg. But there is one eyescore that breakpoint can step into the STL scope where I never have a grip on my variables, just , , etc. I think that there should be a CMake Extension Setting somewhere to enable JustMyCode, which just walks my program. I tried this in CMakeLists.txt since I am using VS2019.

```
if(MSVC)
    add_compile_options(/JMC)
endif()
```

It is supposed to work in a `cl` build. But it's not working when I press Debug in my program entry of the CMake interface. Is JustMyCode Debugging possible in my current toolset?

Comment: I think the config you're looking for is more likely to be found in the C++ extension's settings if it exists. But I could be wrong.